# Two MapRoutes with different data types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a need to have the following C# MVC calls, e.g.:

/SomeController/ActionOne/1/2/3
/SomeController/ActionTwo/1/2/astring

Here are my route maps:

```
routes.MapRoute (
                name: "One",
                url: "SomeController/{action}/{intId1}/{intId2}/{intId3}",
                defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "ActionOne" }
);

routes.MapRoute (
                name: "Two",
                url: "SomeController/{action}/{intId1}/{intId2}/{string1}",
                defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "ActionTwo" }
);
```

and the controller would look something like this:

```
public ActionResult ActionOne ( int intId1, int intId2, int intId3 )
            { ... }
public ActionResult ActionTwo ( int intId1, int intId2, string string1 )
            { ... }
```

When I use the URL */SomeController/ActionTwo/1/2/astring*, This yields the

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter....

I'd like to avoid having to pass an unused parameter simply to get around the routing rule such as */SomeController/ActionTwo/1/2//astring*:

```
public ActionResult ActionOne ( int intId1, int intId2, int? intId3, string? string1 )
            { ... }
public ActionResult ActionTwo ( int intId1, int intId2, int? intId3, string? string1 )
            { ... }
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with map routes, but I'm guessing this is because the routes themselves don't know anything about type, and the MVC framework doesn't attempt to resolve them to pick the correct route.

Comment: You could easily solve this ambiguous situation declaring a different route for the second action. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara  How would I declare a different route?  Wouldn't I need to add another argument to make the pattern different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test it, but you could use constraints on the `Route` attribute on your action. For example with your routing url:

`[Route("SomeController/{action}/{intId1}/{intId2}/{intId3:int}]`

(with the `Route` attribute you can modify the routing url too, essentially solving your problem without bothering of constraints)

On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) you can find a lot more (it's about Web Api, but routing  procedure should be the same).

Actually there's another way to set constraints on your routing url: the `constraints` key in `MapRoute`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "One",
url: "SomeController/{action}/{intId1}/{intId2}/{intId3}",
defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "ActionOne" }
constraints: new{intId3=@"\d+"} 
);
```

Where you can use a Regex too.

Comment: Brilliant!   Thanks Marco -- this worked!   For those looking later, on the Map for the string arg, I used:     **constraints: new { string1= @".+" }**     where the . matches any character.     That map needs to go after the integer (**\d+**) one though!